# remote function with sudo is not giving expected results

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, ksh

1. ssh oraauto works fine ( remote function sum_me )

```
2022-05-24 18:11:07 DEV oracle@HSTTT:~/user> set -x

2022-05-24 18:11:11 DEV oracle@HSTTT:~/user> ssh oraauto@RMT_HST "$(typeset -f sum_me) ; sum_me"

++ typeset -f sum_me

+ ssh oraauto@RMT_HST 'sum_me ()

{

    mem=48;

    if [[ `cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i memtotal | awk '\''{ print int($2/1024/1024)+1 }'\''` -eq $mem ]]; then

        echo "memory test .. passed.";

    else

        echo "memory test .. failed.";

    fi

} ; sum_me'

memory test .. passed.
```

2. ssh oraauto , then sudo run as oracle fails

```
2022-05-24 18:11:18 DEV oracle@HSTTT:~/user> ssh oraauto@RMT_HST "sudo -u oracle ksh -c '$(typeset -f ); sum_me'"

++ typeset -f

+ ssh oraauto@RMT_HST 'sudo -u oracle ksh -c '\''sum_me ()

{

    mem=48;

    if [[ `cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i memtotal | awk '\''{ print int($2/1024/1024)+1 }'\''` -eq $mem ]]; then

        echo "memory test .. passed.";

    else

        echo "memory test .. failed.";

    fi

}; sum_me'\'''

bash: -c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

bash: -c: line 3: `    if [[ `cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i memtotal | awk '{ print int($2/1024/1024)+1 }'` -eq $mem ]]; then'
```

3. ssh oraauto works fine and sudo run as oracle works fine if simple date function.

```
2022-05-24 18:11:31 DEV oracle@HSTTT:~/user> function sum_me { date; }

2022-05-24 18:11:59 DEV oracle@HSTTT:~/user> ssh oraauto@RMT_HST "$(typeset -f sum_me) ; sum_me"

++ typeset -f sum_me

+ ssh oraauto@RMT_HST 'sum_me ()

{

    date

} ; sum_me'

Tue May 24 18:12:07 BST 2022

2022-05-24 18:12:07 DEV oracle@HSTTT:~/user>  ssh oraauto@RMT_HST "sudo -u oracle ksh -c '$(typeset -f ); sum_me'"

++ typeset -f

+ ssh oraauto@RMT_HST 'sudo -u oracle ksh -c '\''sum_me ()

{

    date

}; sum_me'\'''

Tue May 24 18:12:13 BST 2022

2022-05-24 18:12:13 DEV oracle@HSTTT:~/user>
```

> How to fix if function is defined as below

```
function sum_me {
mem=48
if [[ `cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i memtotal | awk '{ print int($2/1024/1024)+1 }'` -eq $mem ]]; then
echo "memory test .. passed."
else
echo "memory test .. failed."
fi
}
```

1. ssh oraauto works fine ( remote function sum_me )
2. ssh oraauto , then sudo run as oracle fails
3. ssh oraauto works fine and sudo run as oracle works fine if simple date function.
4. can some one help me to put workaround
5. how to fix it

Comment: What's the outer shell on the remote system, the one responsible for starting `sudo`? Is it also ksh?

Comment: copied my logic from [link](http://quabr.com:8182/63888808/bash-running-a-function-as-sudo-on-remote-host) I think its sudo which intern calls ksh

Comment: Right as far as it goes, but you're missing a link. ssh starts the remote user's default shell, that shell starts sudo which starts ksh. I'm asking what that shell is, because it's the thing that's doing the first pass at parsing the remote command line before it reaches ksh.

Comment: by default when I login on server shell is bash

Comment: Okay. I _think_ the now-deleted third branch of my answer would work with bash, but am not quite sure -- either way, the two branches still there should definitely work, and I'd appreciate some follow-up if they don't.

Answer (score 0):

You can quote a string to be parsed back to its current value with `printf %q`, as follows:

```
remote_cmd=$(printf '%q ' sudo -u oracle ksh -c "$(typeset -f sum_me); sum_me")
ssh oraauto@RMT_HST "$remote_cmd"
```

You might also consider moving the code to stdin, making it easier to pass straight through (avoiding the question of how it's parsed by the intermediate shell altogether):

```
ssh oraauto@RMT_HST 'sudo -u oracle ksh +li -s' <<EOF
$(typeset -f sum_me)
sum_me
EOF
```

Comment: I tried ``` ssh oraauto@RMT_HST 'sudo -u oracle ksh' <<EOF
$(typeset -f)
sum_me
EOF``` it gets stuck with error "Usage: ulimit [-HSalimits] [limit]"

Comment: Make it `sudo -u oracle ksh -x` and you'll be able to see logs of what went wrong.

Comment: Note that there are a lot of different shells out there under the name ksh. It's not unthinkable to have one that's not as compatible as you'd like with the local one.

Comment: gets stuck ... last 10  lines :  + . /etc/profile.d/which2.sh
+ alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
+ unset i
+ unset -f _src_etc_profile_d
+ unset -f pathmunge
+ trap keybd_trap KEYBD
+ set -o emacs

Comment: That log doesn't show a `ulimit` command anywhere. That said, maybe you want to replace `typeset -f` with `typeset -f sum_me`.

Comment: ksh loads profile which runs "trap keybd_trap KEYBD" hence getting stuck  with bash --noprofile is there similar ksh --noprofile

Comment: Add a `-s`, as in, `sudo -u oracle ksh +li -xs`; that should make the shell a noninteractive non-login shell, preventing it from trying to read configuration files (like `.profile`) that are only for interactive or login shells. Take out the `x`, making it just `+li -s`, when you no longer need debugging.

Comment: (in theory, just `-s` alone should be enough to prevent `-l` or `-i`; this is deliberate overkill)

Comment: same result stuck on trap + alias which='alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
+ unset i
+ unset -f _src_etc_profile_d
+ unset -f pathmunge
+ trap keybd_trap KEYBD
+ set -o emacs

Comment: Have you considered switching to the first form, using `remote_cmd`, instead of continuing to pursue the heredoc approach?

Comment: (I can't reproduce your problem, but I'm using what is probably a much newer ksh than you have).

Comment: I also tried "remote_cmd=$(printf '%q ' sudo -u oracle ksh -c "$(typeset -f sum_me); sum_me")
ssh oraauto@RMT_HST "$remote_cmd""   fails on syntax errror "(" line 148

Comment: I need a `set -x` trace to diagnose that; without it, "line 148" is meaningless.

Comment: Ideally, a **full** trace, not just a few lines in a comment. Please consider using https://gist.github.com/

Comment: Remote_function has always been pain .. If I copy the script in file and run it it runs smoother

Comment: BTW, using backticks instead of `$( )` makes parsing more complicated and failure-prone. If you rewrite your function to avoid them that will leave fewer things that can go wrong. (In particular, the meaning of backslashes and other backticks is different inside a backtick-escaped context)

Comment: I'd rather try to set up a [mre] in an online sandbox like https://repl.it/ rather than interacting with your real system.

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/MajesticAgedAmoebas#main.sh as an example. No, I'm not available for zoom or other interactive development -- that's only available for people who pay my consulting rates. Those rates are somewhat unreasonably high, and my day job has a noncompete that prevents me from offering to consult right now anyhow.

Comment: replaced backticks instead of $( ) still getting error .. I have long code of 254 line in fiunction fails at line 148

Comment: but If I copy function in file with ksh extension and runs the remote function with the location of file script runs fiine

Comment: finally got it working .. there was function within a function, touch_me within function sun_me .. I removed the function touch_me out of sun_me things worked fine

Comment: That kind of issue is why it's important to test that you're showing us code that really does fail in the same ways as your real program.